# Plinq statement gets deadlocked inside static constructor

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, plinq

I came across this situation where the following plinq statement inside static constructor gets deadlocked:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Blah();
}

class Blah
{
     static Blah()
     {
         Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
            .AsParallel()
            .Select(n => n * 3)
            .ToList();
     }
}
```

It happens only when a constructor is static.
Can someone explain this to me please.

Is it TPL bug? Compiler? Me?

Comment: Do you have a windows compiled binary so I can compare the generated MSIL? I'm not convinced this is a library-only issue, and I'm curious :)

Comment: you can download the code and binaries from here:
http://cid-c152e66cc73fcce1.skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=C152E66CC73FCCE1!190

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is generally dangerous to call threading code from a static constructor. In order to ensure that the static constructor executes only once, the CLR executes the static constructor under a lock. If the thread running the static constructor waits on a helper thread, there is a risk that the helper thread is going to need the CLR-internal lock for some reason too, and the program will deadlock.

Here is a simpler code sample that demonstrates the problem:

```
using System.Threading;
class Blah
{
    static void Main() { /* Won’t run because the static constructor deadlocks. */ }

    static Blah()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadBody);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }

    static void ThreadBody() { }
}
```

Section 10.5.3.3 "Races and deadlocks" of the [ECMA CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) guarantees the following:

> Type initialization alone shall not create a deadlock unless some code
>   called from a type initializer (directly or indirectly) explicitly
>   invokes blocking operations.

So, a type initializer (i.e., a static constructor) will not deadlock, provided that no operation in the static constructor blocks the thread. If the static constructor does block, it risks a deadlock.

Comment: It's a very good point. Thanks for the answer. It's just something not intuitive. At least if it has thrown exception somehow...

Answer (score 3):

While the reason has already been explained as to why you wouldn't want to do threaded work inside a static constructor, I thought I'd add that the "right" way to do this instead would be with a static [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx). This is also more efficient as the work to generate those resources will be defferred until those resources are actually needed.

```
class Blah
{
    // Supply factory method to generate the numbers, but actual generation will be deferred
    private static Lazy<List<int>> MyMagicNumbers = new Lazy<List<int>>(Blah.GenerateMagicNumbers);

    public void DoSomethingWithMagicNumbers()
    {
        // Call to Lazy<T>.Value will synchronize any calling threads until value is initially generated from the factory
        List<int> magicNumbers = Blah.MyMagicNumbers.Value;

        // ... do something here ...
    }

    private List<int> GenerateMagicNumbers()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 10000)
                          .AsParallel()
                          .Select(n => n * 3)
                          .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth, the issue does *not* arise on Mono:

```
[mono] /tmp @ dmcs par.cs 
[mono] /tmp @ mono ./par.exe
```

Do you have a windows compiled binary so I can compare the generated MSIL? I'm not convinced this is a library-only issue, and I'm curious :)

---

Comparing the IL was a bit messy, so I decided to just try both binaries on both platforms.
Hehe I revived my old Windows virtual machine just to test this :)

Running the VS compiled binaries on Mono is no problem. You could try it on windows using 2.10.1 (http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html), only 77.4Mb :)

(*I used a custom built mono 2.11 on linux so it could be that the feature support is not complete yet*)

```
     \ run on platform:      MS.Net 4.0      Mono 2.1x
built on: -------------+----------------------------------------
    Visual Studio       |      deadlock       no deadlock
                        |
    MonoDevelop         |      deadlock       no deadlock
```

I also noticed that when running on windows, a CTRL-C is able to break out of the lock.
Will post if I find some more to this.

---

### Update 2

Well, installing Mono runs circles around installing installing VSExpress even on windows. Installing mono has finished in 4 minutes, and resulted in:

```
C:\Users\Seth>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.1\bin\mono.exe" ConsoleApplication2.exe
C:\Users\Seth>
```

No deadlock :) Now all that remains is waiting for VSExpress to be installed (forever) and istall debugging tools (unknown) and than have a crack at it (probably till late night). CU later

Comment: here are a windows binaries:
http://cid-c152e66cc73fcce1.skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?resid=C152E66CC73FCCE1!190

Comment: I'm giving up for the moment. Can't get VSExpress running on a brand new (never running :)) Win7_64 VM. Installing service pack failed (?!) so alas no WinDbg attention from me today

Comment: thanks for the hard work. It seems like a bug in TPL for windows implementation.

Comment: If deadlocking is an expected behavior, I wonder why it doesn't happen in mono. Aren't they locking static constructor?